# ListView displays erratic data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-progressbar, android-cursor

I am using a cursoradapter to populate a listview which contains text, image, and a horizontal progressbar in every row.   Everything is working great except all the information gets mixed up when scrolling up and down through the rows.   I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how the cursor recycles information and when it reloads it it gets mixed up.   I can't seem to find a solution for this, thank you for any help.

```
public class MyDisplayAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    private final Context context;
    private final Cursor c;

    public MyDisplayAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context,c);
        this.context=context;
        this.c=c;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        long Time = new Date().getTime();

        String savedodom=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_ODOM));
        String savedmiles=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_MILES));
        String savedtime=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_Q));

        long timer = Long.valueOf(savedtime);

        long realtime = Time-timer;

        int w = Integer.parseInt(savedmiles);

        int g = Integer.parseInt(savedodom);

        long m = realtime;
        int l = (int) m;

        int frealtime = l/10000;

        int ght = 8640/w;

        int k = frealtime/ght;

        int frd = g+k;

        long bn = (long) frd;

        ImageView imageicon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);


        String eid=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_ID));
        TextView t4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);


        String ename=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_NAME));
        TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        t1.setText(ename);
        if(t1.getText().toString().equals("Brake Pads")){
            imageicon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mtire);
        }
        if(t1.getText().toString().equals("Air Filter")){
            imageicon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.maiffilter);
        }

         String edept=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_DEPT));
         TextView t2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text3);

        String eage=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_AGE));

        int x = Integer.valueOf(eage);
        int x2 = Integer.valueOf(edept);
        int ww = x2+x;
        int trb = ww-frd;
        TextView t3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pg.setProgress(trb);
        pg.setMax(x);

        int pet = pg.getMax();
        int prog = pg.getProgress();
        t2.setText(""+x);
        t4.setText(""+pet);
        t3.setText(""+prog);

        if(trb < 10){
            t3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);
        return rowView;
    }
```

and in my main activity

```
db=new EmployeeDatabase(this);
c=db.query(EmployeeDatabase.EMP_TABLE, null,
        null,null,null,null,null);

MyDisplayAdapter adapter = new MyDisplayAdapter(this, c);// OWN ADAPTER
ListContent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Consider using `Cursor#getInt()` instead of asking for an Integer as a String and then parsing it back into an Integer...

Answer (score 2):

Any time you use an adapter, you should always use if-else instead of just if. You have your bindView method doing:

```
if(t1.getText().toString().equals("Brake Pads")){
    imageicon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mtire);
}
```

which means that if it was true, but isn't anymore, the drawable doesn't get reset. do something like:

```
if(t1.getText().toString().equals("Brake Pads")){
    imageicon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mtire);
}
else {
    imageicon.setBackgroundResource(defaultResourceId)
}
```

Also, just a random suggestion, look into using a ViewHolder since it will help your performance. You cold also dump the cursor row to a [ContentValues](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FContentValues.html&ei=e-F9UN7pLc_iigKVyoCgDw&usg=AFQjCNGGbXSstIL5HE2a-ITa9d9pdKnGXA&sig2=jFV4yuL9Qc33kTczPz5pUw) object so you don't have to call cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(key))

Comment: "just a random suggestion, look into using a ViewHolder" This isn't random, this is great advice! Also, the adapter should store each value for `getColumnIndex()`, there is no need to call this more than once on any column. (I might not use ContentValues though, I think accessing the Cursor more direct.)